# Adding item to cart using requests (Python)

Tags: python, python-requests

Trying to add an item to cart and print the cart cookie. Have done this on some sites with no problems. But the Request Payload looks different on this site. Link to item in trying to add ->

https://www.footish.se/sneakers/nike-wmns-m2k-tekno-ao3108-104bq3378-002

Payload looks like this

```
{"item":{"__type":"JetShop.StoreControls.Services.AddToCartItem","Quantity":"1","AttributeData":["EUR 37.5","","MjQwMzA4fDEwOTkuMDB8LTEuMDB8QlEzMzc4LTAwMi0zNy41fHw8c3BhbiBjbGFzcz0iTWFza2VkSW5TdG9ja0Nzc0NsYXNzIj48c3Bhbj5JIGxhZ2VyPC9zcGFuPjwvc3Bhbj58VHJ1ZXwxfDE=",""],"ProductID":"37127","SpecificationIdList":"","Comments":[],"DiscountId":null},"culture":"sv-SE"
```

This is what i have done so far.

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
payload = {"ProductID": "37127", "Quantity": "1"}
get = s.get("https://www.footish.se/sneakers/fila-wmns-disruptor-slide-1010868-1fg")
post = s.post("https://www.footish.se/Services/General.asmx/AddCartItem", data=payload)
print(post.status_code, post.content)
print(get.status_code, get.text)
```

After trying to add i get an status code "500", and it tells me that 'AddCartItem Web Service method name is not valid'.

Any ideas on how to add the item?

Comment: For the POST try this URL instead : `https://www.footish.se/Services/General.asmx?op=AddCartItem`

Comment: Does not seem to add item to cart using this link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with your code above is because of the Content-Type that your code sent. When we inspect network of link above it shown something like snippet below.

```
:authority: www.footish.se
:method: POST
:path: /Services/General.asmx/AddCartItem
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: id-ID,id;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ko;q=0.6
content-length: 362
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=5nq3ssbdtc1xfkeyu0ugk2jo; JetShop_CartID=6f46a87d-d445-4149-b0f0-8ccea54ee2a8; SERVERID=cl03n04; _ga=GA1.2.973188721.1588161632; _gid=GA1.2.2048936945.1588161632; country_code=SE; RWuid=1588161634615146663; DV_TRACK=9d70aaa2-6a0c-4e56-88d6-3e86623f6c60; 2c.cId=5ea96c6960b2ac677e09f92b; RwServerDebug=false; _pk_ses.438.8ea7=1; JetShop_NoOfItemsInCart=1; __atuvc=3%7C18; __atuvs=5ea96c5ad286a611002; RWviewTrail=37127%2C37127; jibber-367-visitor-token=eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiNDc5MjYyOSIsInR5cGUiOiJjdXN0b21lciJ9.EYr-Gw.jNHbjoGTy97kTcBI5L_-L0WOlBA; _pk_id.438.8ea7=66eea615a6981820.1588161644.1.1588161693.1588161644.
origin: https://www.footish.se
referer: https://www.footish.se/sneakers/nike-wmns-m2k-tekno-ao3108-104bq3378-002
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
```

The website uses `content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8` where if you compare the request sent from your code by adding :

```
print(post.request.headers)
```

the output would be like this.

```
{'Content-Length': '381', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cookie': 'SERVERID=cl03n07; JetShop_CartID=51205d52-9a79-4e35-aa7a-b1cae741fabd; ASP.NET_SessionId=urykwfhot2xdccp0suzk3qst', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

to fix this you need to modify the header and data that being sent to server.

- use json instead of data

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
payload = {"item":{"__type":"JetShop.StoreControls.Services.AddToCartItem","Quantity":"1","AttributeData":["EUR 37.5","","MjQwMzA4fDEwOTkuMDB8LTEuMDB8QlEzMzc4LTAwMi0zNy41fHw8c3BhbiBjbGFzcz0iTWFza2VkSW5TdG9ja0Nzc0NsYXNzIj48c3Bhbj5JIGxhZ2VyPC9zcGFuPjwvc3Bhbj58VHJ1ZXwxfDE=",""],"ProductID":"37127","SpecificationIdList":"","Comments":[],"DiscountId":None},"culture":"sv-SE"}
get = s.get("https://www.footish.se/sneakers/fila-wmns-disruptor-slide-1010868-1fg")
post = s.post("https://www.footish.se/Services/General.asmx/AddCartItem", json=payload)
print(post.request.headers)
print(post.request)
print(post.text)
print(post.status_code)
```

or

- define headers and add `'Content-Type: application/json'` and convert the dict to json using `json.dumps(payload)`

```
import json
import requests
s = requests.Session()
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
payload = {"item":{"__type":"JetShop.StoreControls.Services.AddToCartItem","Quantity":"1","AttributeData":["EUR 37.5","","MjQwMzA4fDEwOTkuMDB8LTEuMDB8QlEzMzc4LTAwMi0zNy41fHw8c3BhbiBjbGFzcz0iTWFza2VkSW5TdG9ja0Nzc0NsYXNzIj48c3Bhbj5JIGxhZ2VyPC9zcGFuPjwvc3Bhbj58VHJ1ZXwxfDE=",""],"ProductID":"37127","SpecificationIdList":"","Comments":[],"DiscountId":None},"culture":"sv-SE"}
get = s.get("https://www.footish.se/sneakers/fila-wmns-disruptor-slide-1010868-1fg")
post = s.post("https://www.footish.se/Services/General.asmx/AddCartItem", data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
print(post.request.headers)
print(post.request)
print(post.text)
print(post.status_code)
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I then used this `cookie = get.cookies
cart = s.post("https://www.footish.se/Services/CartInfoService.asmx/LoadCartInfo", cookie)
print(cart.text)` And was then able to see the item in cart.